# lambda timed out when trying to access mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda

I wrote a simple mongo test, trying to access mongo server in a vpc.
for every run I get : "errorMessage": "*** Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
I have written more handlers in the lambda just to check it.

1. There is no problem connecting to the vpc. other handler (same file) that connects to another server runs well.
2. There is no problem with other modules. I have added another module (make-random-string) and it's running every time.
3. I get no error messages. No exceptions from Mongo. it just times out every time.
4. increasing both memory to 1024 and execution time to 15s didn't help, the results are the same.
5. Mongo driver does not require any C++ builds unless you use kerberos, which I'm not.
6. Test file mimicking the lambda, runs fine.
7. The sample code is here: http://pastebin.com/R2e3jwwa where the db information is removed.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the MongoDB server, on an EC2 instance inside the VPC?

Comment: try with more then one server. one inside and one outside. nothing work, and there is no error or a timeout error from the module. just from lambda.

Comment: Can you connect to MongoDB from other servers?

Answer (score 4):

As weird as it may sound, we finally solved the problem just by changing the `callback(null, response)` to `context.done(null, response)`. This nonsense took us more time than we would have liked to spend here.

You can find more info about the issue here https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/1036

Comment: Sir, I cannot thank you enough. Digging through their documentation, and cloudwatch logs gave me nothing more than a timeout.  

For what it's worth, the first run succeeds, and if `context.done(null, response)` isn't called, i.e. `callback` is, environment variables seem to be overwritten.

Comment: Ha! It drove us crazy, too. There is another solution, which consists on adding `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` at the beginning of your lambda function. You can then use `callback` without timing out

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH... I just spent 4-5 days trying to solve this problem after switching code that was working fine using dynamodb over to mongodb. I learned alot about VPC's in the process atleast.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The solution was to move the database connection object outside the handler method and cache/reuse it.

Here I added more details about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67530789/10664035